# Keras logarithmic loss function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, loss-function

I have to apply following loss function with keras:

[image]

This is my code:

```python
input_shape = self.s_dim[1:]
input_ = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input')
hidden = Dense(self.n_hidden, activation='relu')(input_)
out = Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(hidden)

model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=out, name="ar-model")
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error', optimizer=SGD(lr=self.lr_ar))
return model
```

Does the loss function `mean_squared_logarithmic_error` fit here?

Comment: Look at the definition [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/losses.py#L54) to check out if it fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mean_squared_logarithmic_error is something different than logarithmic loss, which is what you are looking for. Logarithmic loss is the same as crossentropy. You can use binary_crossentropy or categorical_crossentropy, dependent on your output.